# How can we use query to find sum of field via aggregation with some filters?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which contain document like:

```
{ _id: ObjectID(), userName: "aa", amount: 50, date: 1561119425317 }
```

The values which I have for the query are timeStamp1 and timeStamp2.

I want sum of the amount grouped by userName then the query for that is

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match: {date: {$gte: timeStamp1, $lte: timeStamp2}},
{$group: {"_id" : "$userName", total:{"$sum" : "$amount"}}}
])
```

I want the result in parts like I have broken the interval of timeStamp1 to timeStamp2 in 5 parts and then I want the same result for each interval.

How can i do that without running the above query for 5 times (one for each interval).
Cause in future the number of interval might increase to 30 or 40.

Comment: Possible dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657242/mongodb-aggregate-group-for-multiple-date-ranges

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case for [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/)

I can't type down an aggregation example right now, but the documentation for that pipeline stage is quite good.